# R - extract data from json

Tags: r, json, parsing

My dataframe looks like this

```
exmpl <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1),
    json = c("{ \"name\":\"John\", \"age\":30, \"car\":null }")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(json = as.character(json))
```

It contains json formated as character, but my real json is much longer and some jsons includes items that other not. What I need is to filter items that are present in my vector.

```
eq <- c("name", "car")
```

And create new column from it, so result should be.

```
result <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1),
    json = c("{ \"name\":\"John\", \"age\":30, \"car\":null }")
    json_filtered = c("{ \"name\":\"John\", \"car\":null }")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(json = as.character(json))
```

Im looking for dplyr solution, but if you have some nondplyr ideas dont don't hesitate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using `jsonlite`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
exmpl %>%
    mutate(json_filtered = map_chr(list(fromJSON(json)), ~toJSON(.x[names(.x) %in% eq])))
#  id                                    json              json_filtered
#1  1 { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null } {"name":["John"],"car":{}}
```

It might be easier to store filtered entries in a `list` column, in which case you'd do

```
exmpl %>%
    mutate(json_filtered = map(list(fromJSON(json)), ~.x[names(.x) %in% eq]))
```

Column `json_filtered` then contains a `list`, each element of which is a named `list` with entries matched by `eq`.

Comment: @ZcelaAnonymní Not sure what you mean by *"my dataframe have only one row"*. Can you edit your post to include *representative* sample data? It's hard to read code in comments.